# Camera does not output from manomotion ar foundation sample

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used a translator because I am not good at English. Please understand that the sentence can be awkward.

Currently, I use sdk called manomotion for ar foundation and hand tracking

There is a sample provided by manomotion I only build the license key on the sample, but the problem appears as shown in the following screen

The camera screen does not come out, but only the sensor is operated, so only the detected plane appears, and the detected part continues to overlap.

May I know what the problem is?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Mwl.jpg)

I built a sample, and the results are as shown in the picture above

For your information, the device is iPhone 13 Pro